# Multi port usb charger

Tags: power-supply, usb, charger

I want to make a multi port usb "dumb hub" kind of like [this](http://blog.thelifeofkenneth.com/2013/02/diy-usb-power-strip.html).

My question though is if I have a 5v 2500mA power supply, can I just daisy chain them together with out the fuses then connect it to the ground?

Here's a drawing I did to kind of give an idea, I'm still learning how to do all this so sorry if it's a noob question.

**edit:** New drawing
[image: New Drawing]

**edit:** Question two.  If I do it this way, will I be able to charge 5 devices simultaneously?

Comment: You've drawn the ports connected in _series_. At a minimum, they need to be connected in _parallel_. I'll let others note other problems with your scheme.

Comment: No, your drawing won't work. The voltage will drop across each device and you won't get the voltage required to recharge them. It would be better to wire them in parallel so that each device gets 5 volts, but then your current is divided by 5 (assuming they're equal impedance). So you will only be sending 100mA to each device. This only means you won't be able to charge as fast.

Comment: Does this look better? I'm doing this in paint and can't understate how new I am to this.

Comment: That is better. Many times I use EAGLE to draw up quick schematics that do not need simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with connecting multiple power supplies in parallel.

Even though all the supplies have the same nominal output voltage, there will be some inevitable variation.  That means some supplies will take more of the load than some others.  That might matter depending on what the supplies do when they reach their current limit.  If the supplies simply fold back voltage and start regulating current, then it might be OK.  One supply will hit the limit first.  If the load increases more than that, the first supply won't provide any more current and the other supplies will.  However, there are other things supplies can do when you hit their rated current, not all of which would play nice with others connected in parallel.

Another issue is stability.  The controller for each supply was tweaked for that supply and some range of expected load impedance.  Connecting another supply in parallel will likely violate those assumptions, and the whole mess could start oscillating or doing other strange things.

There are supplies that are designed for load sharing.  However, unless the datasheet for your supplies specifically mention this, you have to assume they won't load share nicely.

All in all, if you want a 5 V 2 A supply, you should get a 5 V 2 A supply, not try connecting four 5 V 500 mA supplies together.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have plenty of 5v .5A adapters that work just fine, however the goal is to link them in a single circuit so I can just use one power outlet instead of 5 and charge 5 devices at the same time. I am fully aware these products exist and are cheep, but I want to learn how to do it myself.